# SelectionChanged isn't firing when user changes combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events

So my `selectionChanged` event isn't firing when a user changes it but fires if I change it in code.

I'm using the `selectionchanged` to get a selection from a combobox to fill another combobox.

```html
<!--1st list -->
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding djurKatList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDjurKat}" SelectionChanged="listKat_SelectionChanged" x:Name="listKat" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="98,118,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

<!--2nd list that's filled after something is selected in 1st list-->
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding djurArtList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDjurArt}" x:Name="listDjur" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="98,154,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

In code behind this fills the 2nd combobox and isn't executing when I change the 1st combobox:

```
private void listKat_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{            
    fyllDjurArtLista(hanterare, typeof(Daggdjur));
}
```

When I change the selection in code, `selectionChanged` fires, here below I change my selected `comboboxitem`, the event is fired and 2nd combobox gets filled.

```
var listItem = new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Välj kategori" };
SelectedDjurKat = listItem;
```

Comment: do you use INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [could the SelectionChanged event in WPF be handled only for user interaction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301271/could-the-selectionchanged-event-in-wpf-be-handled-only-for-user-interaction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple example and it works.

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        VM v = new VM();
        v.djurKatList = new List<string>();
        v.djurKatList.Add("1");
        v.djurKatList.Add("2");
        v.djurKatList.Add("3");
        v.djurKatList.Add("4");
        v.djurKatList.Add("5");

        DataContext = v;
    }

    private void listKat_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
       // fyllDjurArtLista(hanterare, typeof(Daggdjur));
    }
}

public class VM {
    public List<string> djurKatList { get; set; }
    public string SelectedDjurKat { get; set; }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <!--1st list -->
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding djurKatList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDjurKat}" SelectionChanged="listKat_SelectionChanged"
                  x:Name="listKat" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="98,118,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

        <!--2nd list that's filled after something is selected in 1st list-->
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding djurArtList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDjurArt}" x:Name="listDjur" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="98,154,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The SelectionChanged is fired. But if the problem is that the other combo box is not filled then you need to use [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229614%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as suggested. You need to call PropertyChanged for the property djurArtList.