# WPF - Fire comboBox SelectedIndexChanged only from user click

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I want to stop the ComboBox_SelectionChanged event from being fired at the UI loading. It should happen only when the user makes some change in the combo box.

To do this, I have written the following in .xam.cs file.

```
  private void myComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender,   SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
      {
        ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
        if (!cb.IsFocused)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
           ViewModel.OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
     }
```

But this does not even fire the event when the user makes the change.
Where have I gone wrong ?

I know there is a similar question in stackoverflow. But the solutions in it did not work for me. pls help.

Comment: Are you following the MVVM design pattern? If so, why are you handling the SelectionChanged Event.  I would recommend binding the Command property if there is one on this combo to a Property in your ViewModel.

Comment: Command property is not available with comboboxes...am I right ? Yes, I checked it , it's not there :(

Comment: Use the SelectedValue property,

Comment: To bind to a Property in your ViewModel

Answer (score 2):

found the solution.
we just need to combine the Selection_Changed event with PreviewMouseDown event.

[could the SelectionChanged event in WPF be handled only for user interaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301271/could-the-selectionchanged-event-in-wpf-be-handled-only-for-user-interaction)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example XAML:

```
<av:ComboBox x:Name="cmbChargeUnit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="548,15,0,0" Width="187" ItemsSource="{av:Binding ChargeUnits}" DisplayMemberPath="ChargeUnitDescription" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedChargeUnit}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFCBCBCB" Height="20" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  SelectedIndex="0"  BorderBrush="#FF7070CB"/>
```

VM:

```
public ChargeUnit SelectedChargeUnit
    {
        get { return _selectedChargeUnit; }
        set
        {
            _selectedChargeUnit = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedChargeUnit");
            if (SelectedAttributeId != null)//Only Load when an attribute is entered
            {
                LoadRates();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can it ever become null ? I have a property like that. But it's always set to some value. It only gets changed when the user changes the items in the combo box

Comment: That part is to check for another property on my ViewModel before calling a method to load rates that use that Property, like I said it is just an example, when you select your item in your combobox it will hit the Set accessor, then you can call a method which will be called everytime this value changes.

Comment: I have already tried that too. That too does the same. Fires the combobox selection changed event at the page loading

Comment: It should not fire an event, as there should not be an event? Just a property? The property should hit its Set accessor when selecting an Item in the combo.  It will hit its Get accessor when the window loads.