# Determine whether Picker.SelectedIndexChanged event was initiated by user

Tags: c#, user-interface, events, xamarin.forms

This is a common problem I have with events that are tied to UI controls. I want to do something with a particular event only if it was initiated directly by the user.

After reading [Determine whether Selector.SelectionChanged event was initiated by a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412280/determine-whether-selector-selectionchanged-event-was-initiated-by-a-user), I realized that one may be able to determine that by examining the sending control. The control may have a property that differs depending on whether or not the user is currently interacting with it.

In this particular case, I am working with a Xamarin.Forms.Picker in a desktop PC app (UWP). I am wondering if there is a property that can tell me whether or not a selectionChanged event was initiated by the user. Surprisingly, the Focused property does NOT seem to be much help. I've seen user-initiated changes where the control is not Focused, and non-user-initiated changes where the control is Focused.

EDIT: I have now opened an issue on this: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9128

Comment: To my knowledge the only case `SelectedindexChanged` is called by system is when the control is rendered when the page is loaded. didn't this help you determine?

Comment: I could certainly track when the page was loaded and ignore if within 1 second of that. I was hoping for something more bulletproof, but I don't know if it's possible. For example, someone might later add code that sets the selected index.

Comment: Universal question.  You can't know it was the user that changed the selection but you definitely know it was your code.  Since you wrote it.  So set a bool variable to true before, to false after.  With a comment on the event handler so a maintainer knows what they forgot to do.

Comment: @William, I want to use picker.IsFocused to check whether user initiate in SelectedindexChanged event, it works fine in Android, but have issue in uwp, so I suggest you can create new thread at github to check it is issue at Xamarin.uwp.